# ¿Como puedo obtener los valores de una fila al accionar un ColumnButton? (C#)

Tags: c#

Quisiera obtener todos los valores de el registro en el cual aplique la accion de "eliminar", esto deberia suceder al darle clic en mi columnButton.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo de la columna Eliminar

```
private void dataTabla_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.ColumnIndex == dataTabla.Columns["btnEliminar"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {


/**  Aqui surge la accion de acuerdo a la columna, en este caso la columna eliminar **/


            }

}
```

Ahora quisiera que los valores de dicho registro, los pudiera obtener al dar clic en el boton.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya me marca el indice de la fila, ahora solo necesitaria saber como puedo acceder a los datos de la fila con el indice de la misma.

**Actualizacion**

Al parecer ya puedo obtener el valor y el indice de mis columnas creadas que serian los botones, pero quiero, obtener el valor de las columnas que fueron llenadas de manera dinamica a travez de una base de datos.

Forma de llenado.

```
string Query = "select Id_Compra,Articulo,Categoria,Obligatorio,Costo,Adquirir from compra";
           MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
           MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);

       MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
       MyAdapter.SelectCommand = MyCommand2;
       DataTable dTable = new DataTable();

       MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);
       dataTabla.DataSource = dTable;
```

Nota: No se como acceder a ellas, porque los indices comienzan desde que los botones fueron creados y no se como acceder al indice o valor de las columnas dinamicas

Creacion de las columnas de los Botones

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn btnEliminar = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
           dataTabla.Columns.Add(btnEliminar);
           btnEliminar.Text = "-";
           btnEliminar.HeaderText = "Eliminar";
           btnEliminar.Name = "btnEliminar";
           btnEliminar.Width = 60;
           btnEliminar.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(2);
           btnEliminar.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes acceder a los valores usando:

```
datagridview1.Rows
[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].
Value.ToString()
```

Para la primera columna seria este código:

```
datagridview1.Rows
[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].
Value.ToString()
```

Para la segunda columna

Answer (score 0):

Accede a la propiedad Rows del DataGridView

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx

```
 var row = this.DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

Debe cambiar la propiedad “SelectionMode” del control gridview. Esto hace que cuando se seleccione una celda se marca toda la fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer clic en el botón se cargan los valores de la fila
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código usado es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Cells[] se coloca el indice de la columna que quiere seleccionar.

Solo debe colocar el código sugerido, cambiando por el nombre apropiado del control gridview en el evento clic del botón que necesite.

Comment: oye no me aparece el atributo RowCommand en mis propiedades dentro de visual studio, ¿se tiene que instalar o algo por el estilo?

Comment: He modificado la respuesta. Quizás te sea útil.

Comment: oye @Fpme eh revisado el funcionamiento de mi tabla y me di cuenta de que toma el indice y valor de cualquiera de las columnas de mis botones, el problema radica en que las demas columnas son llenadas automaticamente y no se porque no puedo acceder ni a su indice ni a su atributo, la publicacion ha sido actualizada.